# Error on mongos server

Tags: mongodb, configuration, errors

Firstly,I am new to mongodb.  when we executed the below command on mongos server.

```
/usr/bin/mongos --configdb X.X.X.1:20001,X.X.X.2:20002,X.X.X.3:20003 --port 27017 --chunkSize 1
```

we are getting the below error:

```
2014-12-01T14:40:24.947+0300 [Balancer] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [X.X.X.1:20001]
2014-12-01T14:40:24.947+0300 [Balancer] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [X.X.X.2:20002]
2014-12-01T14:40:24.948+0300 [Balancer] SyncClusterConnection connecting to [X.X.X.3:20003]
2014-12-01T14:40:24.957+0300 [Balancer] scoped connection to X.X.X.1:20001,X.X.X.2:20002,X.X.X.3:20003 not being returned to the pool
2014-12-01T14:40:24.957+0300 [Balancer] caught exception while doing balance: error checking clock skew of cluster X.X.X.1:20001,X.X.X.2:20002,X.X.X.3:20003 :: caused by :: 13650 clock skew of the cluster X.X.X.1:20001,X.X.X.2:20002,X.X.X.3:20003 is too far out of bounds to allow distributed locking.
```

Kindly let us know what it meant by. weather it is  properly connected with config server or not?

Answer (score 1):

Check your mongos, mongod and config servers NTP settings. The clocks on every member of the cluster must return the same datetime. Use the "date" command on linux to verify it.